# Downloading a file in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, download

A google search shows a few examples on how to download a file in Delphi but most are buggy and half of the time don't work in my experience.

I'm looking for a simple robust solution which will let me download a single exe (for updating my app) and will hold the execution of the current update thread until the download is done or errors out.  The process is already threaded so the download code should hold execution until it's done (hopefully).

Here's two implementations, both seem very complicated
    1. http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0116.htm
    2. http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/a/get_file_net.htm

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The second approach is the standard way of using Internet resources using WinINet, a part of Windows API. I have used it a lot, and it has always worked well. The first approach I have never tried. (Neither is "very complicated". There will always be a few additional steps when using the Windows API.)

If you want a very simple method, you could simply call [`UrlMon.URLDownloadToFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(VS.85).aspx). You will not get any fine control (at all!) about the download, but it is very simple.

Example:

```
URLDownloadToFile(nil,
                  'http://www.rejbrand.se',
                  PChar(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'download.htm'),
                  0,
                  nil);
```

Comment: Hint: replace `Application.ExeName` with `ParamStr(0)` to remove the dependency on the `Forms` unit.

Comment: @mjustin: True. But in production code, you will not want to save files to the application's directory anyway, which is read-only (Program Files), unless the program is portable (runs on a USB stick for example).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andreas.  I went with the second approach which I posted since you said it was the standard, hopefully it turns out to be reliable.  Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasRejbrand ! That's exatcly what I was looking for!

Comment: keep that in mind; internet explorers download history does not allow you to download most recent version of the file you are downloading.. so using IE api is 
probably faster but not the best way to download a file in all cases..

Comment: Does not work on Windows Servers anymore.

Answer (score 19):

Why not make use of Indy? If you use the `TIdHTTP` component, it's simple:

```
procedure TMyForm.DownloadFile;    
var
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  Url, FileName: String;
begin    
  Url := 'http://www.rejbrand.se';
  Filename := 'download.htm';

  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Get(Url, Stream);
    Stream.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
    IdHTTP1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You can even add a progress bar by using the `OnWork` and `OnWorkBegin` events:

```
procedure TMyForm.IdHTTPWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;AWorkCountMax: Int64);
begin
  ProgressBar.Max := AWorkCountMax;
  ProgressBar.Position := 0;
end;

procedure TMyForm.IdHTTPWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
begin
  ProgressBar.Position := AWorkCount;
end;

procedure TMyForm.DownloadFile;    
var
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  Url, FileName: String;
begin    
  Url := 'http://www.rejbrand.se';
  Filename := 'download.htm';

  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.OnWorkBegin := IdHTTPWorkBegin;
    IdHTTP1.OnWork := IdHTTPWork;
    IdHTTP1.Get(Url, Stream);
    Stream.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
    IdHTTP1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I'm not sure if these events fire in the context of the main thread, so any updates done to VCL components may have to be done using the `TIdNotify` component to avoid threading issues. Maybe someone else can check that.

Comment: If the file is large  you may want to use a file stream rather than a memory stream.

Comment: If your app use networking only for update procedure - then using Indy will increase .exe size.

Comment: How exactly do I acess the IdHTTPWorkBegin procedure to modify it?

Comment: @Codex `IdHTTPWorkBegin()` is a procedure that you would write and then assign to the `TIdHTTP.OnWork` event. I have updated the answer to show this.

Comment: @MikeTaylor "*I'm not sure if these events fire in the context of the main thread*" - they are fired in the context of the thread that calls `TIdHTTP.Get()`, so yes, if `TIdHTTP` is used in a worker thread then UI updates will have to be synchronized with the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

For people that has later version of delphi, you can use this:

```
var
  http : TNetHTTPClient;
  url : string;
  stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  http := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    url := YOUR_URL_TO_DOWNLOAD;
    http.Get(url, stream);
    stream.SaveToFile('D:\Temporary\1.zip');
  finally
    stream.Free;
    http.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -2):

Using URLMon.

```
errcode := URLMon.URLDownloadToFile(nil,
                      PChar('http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?345726-DELPHI-Download-Files'),
PChar( 'a:\download.htm'),
      0,
      nil);
if errcode > 0 then
      showmessage('Error while downloading: ' + inttostr(errcode));
```

Comment: Isn't this basically a copy of my eight-year-old answer? :)

Comment: I don't think so.