# How do I add a progress bar to a download with IdHTTP

Tags: delphi

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506251/downloading-a-file-in-delphi#:%7E:text=You%20can%20even%20add%20a%20progress%20bar%20by%20using%20the%20OnWork%20and%20OnWorkBegin%20Events) comment on a post regarding file downloads and found that it mentiones adding a `TProgressbar` that shows the download progress. I tried adding the `OnWork` procedure in my unit but that unfortunately did not work as the unit did not recognize `TWorkMode`. I also tried cloning the `IdHTTP` unit file and adding the procedure, but that turned out to be pointless.

I am using this code to download the file

```
  Url := filetodownloadvar;
  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
    IdHTTP1.Get(Url, Stream);
    Stream.SaveToFile(FileName);
finally
    Stream.Free;
    IdHTTP1.Free;
```

My `TProgressbar` is labels ProgressBar1, I have not given it any name.

How do I make that progressbar work?

Comment: If your code does not recognize some identifier, then the solution is figuring out which unit you need to add to `uses` clause. Make sure that you have `IdComponent` there.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I added that in the unit and it works. But the problem is not gone. I need to somehow link the `IdHTTP` variables `OnWork` actions to the procedure.

Comment: You need to assign `OnWork` events.  `IdHTTP1.OnWork := IdHTTPWork`, where `IdHTTPWork` is name of your on work event handler.